# How to implement swipe gesture used in Word-Link Game using react-native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, swipe, multi-touch

I am trying to make a game similar to Word-Link. I want to swipe between multiple letters and create a word. How can i implement this in React-Native. One idea i had was to use the patter lock system but i am still posting this query to find if there is a better way to do it. Currently I am using ToucableOpacity to press the button and generate words.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4iKW.jpg

```
            <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.addLetters(alpha4[0])
            // Alert.alert("A")
            box1 = alpha4[0]

            this.setState({ box1: box1 })
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'beige' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', justifyContent: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', textAlign: 'center', borderWidth: 5 }}>{alpha4[0]}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This npm package provides functionality for detecting swipe gestures in react-native
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures

Comment: How do i connect multiple components using this npm package?

Answer (score 0):

`onDrag`, `onDrop`, `onMouseMove`. Which, for phone on react-native you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215332/10566281). `onStartShouldSetResponder`, `onResponderGrant`, `onResponderMove`.