# Detect swipe in react native on press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to detect swipe up/down/left/right on a div(touchableOpacity) after long-press in react native. Just swipe up will do, for now, as I can make the others on my own using that.
So the process would be

1. long press a container
2. call a function that starts tracking the touches and uses if/else to decide if swipe up or not

   <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={()=>swipeUp()}/>

where swipe will be something like this

```
 const swipeUp = () => {
    //track touch start y axis
    //track touch end y axis
    //if difference greater than 10, it's swipe up
    // randomFunctionCalled
    //else no response
}
```

I don't want to use any complicated library and I already tried the simple ones which didn't give optimal performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check when the press is on using `onPressIn`,
Then get the coordinates of your press, (put it on the main View, this might help [React native get the coordinates of my touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862765/react-native-get-the-coordinates-of-my-touch-event) )
Then when the press is out and see it's coordinates
Then get the difference between them