# How can I scroll through a ScrollView from anywhere on the screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, carousel, react-native-scrollview

I built a carousel in react native. Now I want to be able to scroll through it even when my finger is not placed inside it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the coordinates and check the direction if they change. if left or right, trigger swipe.

**pseudocode:**

```
if (x.now > x.just now) { swipeRight()}
if (x.now < x.just) {swipeLeft()}
```

may this helps: [React native get the coordinates of my touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862765/react-native-get-the-coordinates-of-my-touch-event)